# How to add a src as well as my header at the same line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I need to show my header line as well as the logo.png at the same line. Here is my try.

```
     <div class="header">
             <a>Dashboard</a>
             <div> 
             <a href="../test.php" > <img src="../assets/images/logo.png"  width="50" height="50"/> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></a>
            
             <a href="logout.php" style="margin-left: 2em"><i class="fa fa-toggle-left"></i> logout</a>
            </div>
    
         </div>
```

I could see the png image but it has not nicely fit with the header bar. Here is the output

[image]

But I need to show Dashboard,username and the logout in a same line which goes through the middle of the image.

I will put my styles as below,

```
.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
    
}
```

Can someone help me in this case?

Dashboard, james and logout should be in the same line,

[image]

Comment: Could you update your question with what is your desired outcome? Maybe a screenshot, a mockup, a simple drawing?

Comment: updated answer here

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items: center` in your .header class to center everything vertically.

You can find more information about align-items [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

Answer (score 0):

You set display flex in header class just you need to add a CSS property `align-items: center;` use the below code

```css
.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Flexbox` is the right tool for this. You can easily align your items the way you need and want!

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.header>h4 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.user-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.user-info>img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.user-info > button {
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h4>Dashboard</h4>
  <div class="user-info">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS58k.jpg?s=256&g=1" />
    <label>James</label>
    <button>Logout</button>
  </div>
</div>
```